# Cannot add a leaflet.pattern pattern to Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet-plugins

I'm using the leaflet.pattern npm package. What am I missing? My Leaflet map is in a Vuejs application.

Maybe I need to correct the import statements?

```
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet.pattern/dist/leaflet.pattern-src.js";

  var myMap = L.map("leafletMapId", {
    layers: [streetTilesLayer],
    scrollWheelZoom: true
  }).setView(this.center, this.zoom);


  var simpleStripePattern = new L.StripePattern();
  simpleStripePattern .addTo(myMap);
```

No pattern appears on the map.

I have also tried this...

```
  var myPattern = new L.StripePattern();
  var shape = new L.PatternRect({
    x: 5,
    y: 5,
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    rx: 10,
    ry: 10,
    fill: true
  });
  myPattern.addShape(shape);
  myPattern.addTo(myMap);
```

Again, no pattern appears on the map.

I also tried adding these additional import statements and this did not have an effect...

```
import "leaflet.pattern/dist/leaflet.pattern.js";
import "leaflet.pattern/src/StripePattern.js";
import "leaflet.pattern/src/PatternPath.js";
import "leaflet.pattern/src/PatternRect.js";
```

This code resulted in an error that might provide insight...
      var shape = new L.PatternRect({
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        rx: 10,
        ry: 10,
        fill: true
      });

```
  var pattern = new L.Pattern({ width: 50, height: 50 });
  pattern.addShape(shape);
  pattern.addTo(myMap);

  var circle = new L.Circle(this.center, 400.0, {
    fillPattern: pattern,
    fillOpacity: 1.0
  });
  circle.addTo(myMap);
```

The error:

> Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at NewClass._updateStyle [as _superUpdateStyle] (leaflet.pattern-src.js?3913:216)
>       at NewClass._updateStyle [as _superUpdateStyle] (leaflet.pattern-src.js?3913:217)
>       at NewClass._updateStyle [as _superUpdateStyle] (leaflet.pattern-src.js?3913:217)
>       at NewClass._updateStyle [as _superUpdateStyle] (leaflet.pattern-src.js?3913:217)
>       at NewClass._updateStyle [as _superUpdateStyle] (leaflet.pattern-src.js?3913:217)
>       at NewClass._updateStyle [as _superUpdateStyle] (leaflet.pattern-src.js?3913:217)